# How to check if user click on route between which waypoints (google map direction)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google Mapping services, and able to render route between given Origin and Destination and way points.
In same app we allow user to click on route displayed.
Now, my problem is to find closest way points from point(user clicked).

ex:
Origin      : A
Way Point   : B
Way Point   : C
Destination : D

Now, how to get in java script if user clicks between A&B or B&C or C&D?

Its Urgent, any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!